# C# using DevIL library in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devil

I want to use the ilLoadL function from the devIL library using C#. But when I try to add DevIL.dll to my project it gives me this error:

> A reference to the "DevIL.dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Now i've been searching online for a while and it seems that DevIL does not support .NET? There is a .NET wrapper created for it. I tried that but it doesn't contain the ilLoadL function and such. Only the LoadBitmap and LoadILU.

Is there a way to use DevILs ilLoadL function in C#?

Comment: The devILs library might not work correctly, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453094/calling-c-dll-function-from-c-sharp for the answer to calling dll functions from c#

Comment: It is an unmanaged library, you cannot directly use it from C#.  Google "devil c# wrapper" to find a wrapper.

Comment: I have only found a wrapper that doesn't support the ilLoadL function. Is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the nuget package? http://www.nuget.org/packages/DevIL.redist/

Comment: I installed the package, how can I access devIL this way? I am fairly new to NuGet.

Comment: You should now be able to use the library as if it were a normal reference. For example:

`System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = DevIL.DevIL.LoadBitmap(filename);`

Comment: Not working for me. Can't access the library in any way. It says it is installed succesfully but when I got to package manager there are no installed packages. Somehow to library is still not working

Comment: If you open up the references folder, does it appear in there?

Comment: No it doesn't... Maybe something went wrong when installing it?

Comment: Right click on project references > Add Library Package Reference